# How to add a character at the beginning of an existing string in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

How do I add a single character such as a '`$`' or a '`+`' at the beginning of an existing string?

I tried using the appendingString method but that adds the `$` or `+` at the end of the string.

I know I can always save the `$` or `+` in a new string and then append the other string, but I just want to know if there is a better way to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried [@"$" stringByAppendingString: str ]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is actually very simple:

```
[@"+" stringByAppendingString:existingString];
```

This should definitely work for you :)  And the `+` will be at the beginning.

Comment: This solution was mentioned in the question.

Comment: @JoshCaswell The function was, but he said when he used it it always added the + at the END of the function. That means he was doing it in reverse--like this: `[existingString stringByAppendingString:@"+"];`  I fixed it.

Comment: From the question: «I know I can always save the $ or + in a new string and then append the other string»

Answer (score 4):

Strings aren't mutable. You're creating a new string when you use `stringByAppendingString:` In order to prepend, you would have to make a mutable version of your existing string and then use [`insertString:atIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000156-insertString_atIndex_) like so:

```
[[NSMutableString stringWithString:myString] insertString:@"$" atIndex:0];
```

Why there isn't a `stringByPrependingString:`, I don't know.

The best solution is the one you've already mentioned:

```
[@"$" stringByAppendingString:myString];
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as the string is mutable, i.e. it is an NSMutableString you can use.

```
[str insertString:@"$" atIndex:0];
```

Have a read of the docs here, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutablestring_Class/Reference/Reference.html